# Get additional data stored in Oauth2 token in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Currently I'm developing a rest controller in a Spring Boot app that uses Oauth2 tokens for authentication and I need to get some user info from the token.

To get the basic info I'm using the OAuth2Authentication object like this:

```
@RequestMapping(CONTROLLER_PATH)
public DataDto getActivityData(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id,OAuth2Authentication auth) {

 . . .

}
```

But there are some custom fields in the token that are not included in this object.

Is there any way to read those fields in the controller or map them to an object?